# Primefaces Tree doesnt update itself

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tree, el, updates

I have a page with a primefaces tree component and a simple box. Everytime when a tree node is selected the box and the tree itself should be updated. If I only set the update-value for the box it works all fine, but if I also set it for the tree itself, it works only one time.
I guess there's a problem with javascript and the tree initialisation.

My xhtml-content (doens't work - remove "myTree" in update then it works):

```
<p:tree id="myTree" value="#{anyBean.someNodes}" var="node"
        selectionMode="single" selection="#{anyBean.selectedNode}">
    <p:ajax event="select" update="myTree :#{component.parent.namingContainer.clientId}:bla"
            listener="#{anyBean.selectionChanged}" />
    <p:treeNode>
        <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>

<p:outputPanel id="bla">
    <div id="some-refresh-counter" />
    <script>
        jQuery('#some-refresh-counter').text( (new Date()).getTime() );
    </script>
</p:outputPanel>
```

My Bean:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class AnyBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3034385964446796122L;
    private static Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(AnyBean.class);

    private TreeNode someNodes;
    private TreeNode selectedNode;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.someNodes = new DefaultTreeNode("Root");

        new DefaultTreeNode("A", this.someNodes);
        new DefaultTreeNode("B", this.someNodes);
        new DefaultTreeNode("C", this.someNodes);
        new DefaultTreeNode("D", this.someNodes);
        new DefaultTreeNode("E", this.someNodes);

        this.selectedNode = null;

        LOG.debug("initialized...");
    }

    public void selectionChanged(NodeSelectEvent event) {
        LOG.debug("selection changed to " + event.getTreeNode().getData());
    }


    public TreeNode getSomeNodes() {
        return someNodes;
    }

    public void setSomeNodes(TreeNode someNodes) {
        this.someNodes = someNodes;
    }

    public TreeNode getSelectedNode() {
        return selectedNode;
    }

    public void setSelectedNode(TreeNode selectedNode) {
        this.selectedNode = selectedNode;
    }
}
```

I'am using:

- Primefaces: 5.0
- JSF: 2.2.6
- Java: 1.7.0_71
- Tomcat: 7.0.55

kind regards

**EDIT**
I just found out, that if I set the update attribute to the name of the containing form it will work perfectly. example:

```
<h:form id="fooform">
    <p:tree id="myTree" value="#{anyBean.someNodes}" var="node"
            selectionMode="single" selection="#{anyBean.selectedNode}">
        <p:ajax event="select" update=":fooform"
                listener="#{anyBean.selectionChanged}" />
```

but as soon i use **EL** it stopped working:

```
<h:form id="fooform">
    <p:tree id="myTree" value="#{anyBean.someNodes}" var="node"
            selectionMode="single" selection="#{anyBean.selectedNode}">
        <p:ajax event="select" update="#{&quot;:fooform&quot;}"
                listener="#{anyBean.selectionChanged}" />
```

**EDIT #2 (work-around)**

I think the problem is the         -tag. I removed it and added a command-link to my node outputtext and the update works fine, but the selectedNode attribute wasn't updated.
Thats why i am still using         -tag, but executing a jQuery on completion, which clicks an command link which updates the form:

```
<h:form id="fooform">
    <p:commandLink style="display: none;" id="refresh-link" value="refresh-link" update="#{component.namingContainer.clientId}" />
    <p:tree id="myTree" value="#{anyBean.someNodes}" var="node"
            selectionMode="single" selection="#{anyBean.selectedNode}">
        <p:ajax event="select" update=":fooform"
                listener="#{anyBean.selectionChanged}"
                oncomplete="jQuery('#' + jQuery(this)[0].source.split(':').shift() + '\\:refresh-link').click()" />
        <p:treeNode>
            <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>
```

Comment: Did you try with `@this` instead of `myTree` ?

Comment: yes i did, but it did not work